# Airflow scheduler error No such file or directory: 'airflow': 'airflow'

Tags: python-3.x, linux, airflow, redhat

I'm having a problem with an airflow server where any time I try and run a dag I get the following error:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'airflow': 'airflow'`

All dags stay in in a queued state unless I set them to a running state or mark the previous task as successful.  The previous tasks don't determine if the task fails.

Everything was working working before yesterday (3/23) and this issue is fairly recent.  It started after a restart of Airflow's Webserver and Airflow's Scheduler.  Those were stopped to troubleshoot a dag issue and since nothing was changed shouldn't have any relevance except for the fact that the issue started after the restart of those two.  Also, there have been no changes to Airflow, the dags, or the database, aside from Airflow's use of it, after the previous start up of the two and the restart.

I'm not sure if this is the cause of the dags and tasks staying in queued state or if the problem lies elsewhere, but this is the best info I have to start.

I've included all that I can think of.

The system is Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 with Airflow 2.2.4 and using MySQL 8 as the database.  It has Python 3.6, I'm not sure if this is the root issue.  Airflow is run under as an airflow user that has sudo access.

The scheduler is running LocalExecutor with StandardTaskRunner.  I have tried combinations of LocalExecutor, SequentialExecutor, StandardTaskRunner, and CGroupTaskRunner.  I don't have Celery, Dask, or Kubernetes setup as this is an initial test of Airflow.

This is what shows up in the dag_process_manager.log:

```
DAG File Processing Stats

File Path                                                                                            PID  Runtime      # DAGs    # Errors  Last Runtime    Last Run
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  ------  ---------  --------  ----------  --------------  -------------------
/opt/airflow/dags/e_transaction_scheduler.py                                                                             1           0  0.55s           2022-03-24T16:59:49
/opt/airflow/dags/authdb_transaction_scheduler.py                                                                           1           0  0.90s           2022-03-24T16:59:49
/opt/airflow/dags/c_transaction_scheduler.py                                                                             1           0  0.62s           2022-03-24T16:59:49
/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/smart_sensor_dags/smart_sensor_group.py                            5           0  0.70s           2022-03-24T16:59:49
/opt/airflow/dags/edge_transaction_history.py                                                     316700  0.01s            13           0  0.25s           2022-03-24T16:59:51
================================================================================
[2022-03-24 09:59:56,090] {manager.py:663} INFO - Searching for files in /opt/airflow/dags
[2022-03-24 09:59:56,095] {manager.py:666} INFO - There are 6 files in /opt/airflow/dags
[2022-03-24 09:59:59,045] {manager.py:784} INFO -
================================================================================
```

The scheduler log for this dag just contains this over and over.  Right now I'm using a single dag for troubleshooting.

```
[2022-03-24 10:47:24,444] {processor.py:163} INFO - Started process (PID=336612) to work on /opt/airflow/dags/authdb_transaction_scheduler.py
[2022-03-24 10:47:24,446] {processor.py:642} INFO - Processing file /opt/airflow/dags/authdb_transaction_scheduler.py for tasks to queue
[2022-03-24 10:47:24,447] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - [2022-03-24 10:47:24,447] {dagbag.py:500} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /opt/airflow/dags/authdb_transaction_scheduler.py
[2022-03-24 10:47:24,489] {processor.py:654} INFO - DAG(s) dict_keys(['authdb_transaction_scheduler']) retrieved from /opt/airflow/dags/authdb_transaction_scheduler.py
[2022-03-24 10:47:24,506] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - [2022-03-24 10:47:24,505] {dag.py:2398} INFO - Sync 1 DAGs
[2022-03-24 10:47:24,533] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - [2022-03-24 10:47:24,533] {dag.py:2937} INFO - Setting next_dagrun for authdb_transaction_scheduler to None
[2022-03-24 10:47:24,542] {processor.py:171} INFO - Processing /opt/airflow/dags/authdb_transaction_scheduler.py took 0.102 seconds
[2022-03-24 10:47:29,751] {processor.py:163} INFO - Started process (PID=336647) to work on /opt/airflow/dags/authdb_transaction_scheduler.py
[2022-03-24 10:47:29,752] {processor.py:642} INFO - Processing file /opt/airflow/dags/authdb_transaction_scheduler.py for tasks to queue
[2022-03-24 10:47:29,753] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - [2022-03-24 10:47:29,753] {dagbag.py:500} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /opt/airflow/dags/authdb_transaction_scheduler.py
[2022-03-24 10:47:29,794] {processor.py:654} INFO - DAG(s) dict_keys(['authdb_transaction_scheduler']) retrieved from /opt/airflow/dags/authdb_transaction_scheduler.py
[2022-03-24 10:47:29,807] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - [2022-03-24 10:47:29,806] {dag.py:2398} INFO - Sync 1 DAGs
[2022-03-24 10:47:29,830] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - [2022-03-24 10:47:29,830] {dag.py:2937} INFO - Setting next_dagrun for authdb_transaction_scheduler to None
[2022-03-24 10:47:29,838] {processor.py:171} INFO - Processing /opt/airflow/dags/authdb_transaction_scheduler.py took 0.090 seconds
```

The contents of the wait_for_previous_run:

```
[2022-03-24 10:04:11,960] {taskinstance.py:1037} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: authdb_transaction_scheduler.wait_for_previous_run manual__2022-03-24T17:04:09.925464+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-03-24 10:04:11,960] {taskinstance.py:1243} INFO -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-03-24 10:04:11,960] {taskinstance.py:1244} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 154
[2022-03-24 10:04:11,960] {taskinstance.py:1245} INFO -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-03-24 10:04:11,973] {taskinstance.py:1264} INFO - Executing <Task(SqlSensor): wait_for_previous_run> on 2022-03-24 17:04:09.925464+00:00
[2022-03-24 10:04:11,975] {base_task_runner.py:136} INFO - Running on host: airflow.xyz.com
[2022-03-24 10:04:11,976] {base_task_runner.py:137} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'authdb_transaction_scheduler', 'wait_for_previous_run', 'manual__2022-03-24T17:04:09.925464+00:00', '--job-id', '61611', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/authdb_transaction_scheduler.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpuei73qnh', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmpvqxdj593']
```

The log from the next task extract_merchant_account (this just keeps getting rescheduled after marking the wait task as successful):

```
[2022-03-24 10:23:06,831] {taskinstance.py:1037} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: authdb_transaction_scheduler.extract_merchant_account manual__2022-03-24T17:04:09.925464+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-03-24 10:23:06,831] {taskinstance.py:1243} INFO -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-03-24 10:23:06,831] {taskinstance.py:1244} INFO - Starting attempt 4 of 4
[2022-03-24 10:23:06,831] {taskinstance.py:1245} INFO -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-03-24 10:23:06,844] {taskinstance.py:1264} INFO - Executing <Task(SSHOperator): extract_merchant_account> on 2022-03-24 17:04:09.925464+00:00
[2022-03-24 10:23:06,846] {base_task_runner.py:136} INFO - Running on host: airflow.xyz.com
[2022-03-24 10:23:06,846] {base_task_runner.py:137} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'authdb_transaction_scheduler', 'extract_merchant_account', 'manual__2022-03-24T17:04:09.925464+00:00', '--job-id', '61731', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/authdb_transaction_scheduler.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpe8za_ayj', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmpeb3agndg']
```

Here's the dag file authdb_transactions_scheduler:

```
from airflow import DAG
#from airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator import SSHOperator
from airflow.providers.ssh.operators.ssh import SSHOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.sensors.sql_sensor import SqlSensor
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
import time






default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2022, 3, 23),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False
    }

with DAG('authdb_transaction_scheduler', schedule_interval= None, catchup=False, default_args=default_args) as dag:

    wait_for_previous_run = SqlSensor(
        task_id='wait_for_previous_run',
        sql='''
select poll from ( select poll from( select case when state = "running" then 0 else 1 end as poll, execution_date from dag_run 
where dag_id = "{{ dag.dag_id }}" and execution_date < REPLACE( SUBSTRING_INDEX("{{execution_date}}", "+", 1), 'T', ' ' ) 
group by execution_date, state order by execution_date desc limit 1 ) a 
) a  union all ( SELECT 1 as poll FROM (
SELECT count(1) AS count FROM dag_run WHERE dag_id = "{{ dag.dag_id }}" and execution_date < REPLACE( SUBSTRING_INDEX("{{execution_date}}", "+", 1), 'T', ' ' ) ) a 
WHERE count = 0
) order by poll desc
            ''',
        poke_interval=300,
        retries=153,
        conn_id='airflow_dag',
        dag=dag
    )

    # delay_task = PythonOperator(
        # task_id="delay_task",
        # dag=dag,
        # python_callable=lambda: time.sleep(120)
    # )

    merchant_account = """
        cd /script_location/scripts/;
        bash extract_mongoDB_data.sh mongoDB_data_extraction_config_dev.csv AuthDB.MERCHANTACCOUNTS
        """

    extract_merchant_account = SSHOperator(
                ssh_conn_id='ssh_extract',
                task_id='extract_merchant_account',
                command=merchant_account,
                dag=dag
        )
    
    ingest_merchant_account = """
        cd /script_location/scripts/;
        bash data_ingestion.sh AuthDB.merchant_accounts.?????????????????.json N;
        """

    ingestion_merchant_account = SSHOperator(
                ssh_conn_id='ssh_load',
                task_id='ingestion_merchant_account',
                command=ingest_merchant_account,
                dag=dag
        )

    loading_merchant_account = """
        cd /script_location/scripts;
        bash trigger_bqload.sh AuthDB.merchant_accounts append;
        """

    load_merchant_account = SSHOperator(
                ssh_conn_id='ssh_load',
                task_id='load_merchant_account',
                command=loading_merchant_account,
                dag=dag
        )
    wait_for_previous_run >> extract_merchant_account >> ingestion_merchant_account >> load_merchant_account
```

Both the webserver and the scheduler have been setup to be ran by systemd.  Here's the services file for airflow-scheduler:

```
    #
    # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    # or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    # distributed with this work for additional information
    # regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    # to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    # "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    # with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
    #
    #   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    #
    # Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    # software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    # "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
    # KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    # specific language governing permissions and limitations
    # under the License.
    
    [Unit]
    Description=Airflow scheduler daemon
    After=network.target mysqld.service
    Wants=mysqld.service
    
    [Service]
    EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/airflow
    User=airflow
    Group=airflow
    Type=simple
    ExecStart=/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow scheduler \
        --pid $AIRFLOW_SCHDLRPID \
        --log-file $AIRFLOW_SCHDLRLOG \
        --subdir $AIRFLOW_DAGS
    ExecStop=/bin/kill '/bin/cat $AIRFLOW_SCHDLRPID'
    Restart=always
    RestartSec=5s
    
    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here's the airflow-webserver:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.

[Unit]
Description=Airflow webserver daemon
After=network.target mysqld.service airflow-scheduler.service
Wants=mysqld.service airflow-scheduler.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/airflow
User=airflow
Group=airflow
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow webserver \
    --port 8443 \
    --ssl-cert $AIRFLOW_SSLCRT \
    --ssl-key $AIRFLOW_SSLKEY \
    --pid $AIRFLOW_PID \
    --log-file $AIRFLOW_LOGFILE \
    --access-logfile $AIRFLOW_LOGACCS \
    --error-logfile $AIRFLOW_LOGERR
ExecStop=/bin/kill '/bin/cat $AIRFLOW_PID'
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here are the environmental variables set:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.

# This file is the environment file for Airflow. Put this file in /etc/sysconfig/airflow per default
# configuration of the systemd unit files.
#
AIRFLOW_HOME=/opt/airflow
AIRFLOW_PID=/run/airflow/webserver.pid
AIRFLOW_CONFIG=/home/airflow/airflow/airflow.cfg
AIRFLOW_SSLCRT=/ssl_location/xyz.com.crt
AIRFLOW_SSLKEY=/ssl_location/xyz.com.key
AIRFLOW_SSLCA=/ssl_location/xyz-ca.crt
AIRFLOW_LOGACCS=/var/log/airflow/webserver-access.log
AIRFLOW_LOGERR=/var/log/airflow/webserver-error.log
AIRFLOW_LOGFILE=/var/log/airflow/webserver.log
AIRFLOW_SCHDLRPID=/run/airflow/scheduler.pid
AIRFLOW_SCHDLRLOG=/var/log/airflow/scheduler/scheduler.log
AIRFLOW_DAGS=/opt/airflow/dags
```

Here is the output from running `airflow config list`:

```
    [core]
    dags_folder = /opt/airflow/dags
    hostname_callable = socket.getfqdn
    default_timezone = PST8PDT
    executor = LocalExecutor
    sql_alchemy_conn = mysql+mysqldb://airflowdbuser:some_password@localhost:3306/airflow_db
    sql_engine_encoding = utf-8
    sql_alchemy_pool_enabled = True
    sql_alchemy_pool_size = 5
    sql_alchemy_max_overflow = -1
    sql_alchemy_pool_recycle = 1800
    sql_alchemy_pool_pre_ping = True
    sql_alchemy_schema = airflow_db
    parallelism = 200
    max_active_tasks_per_dag = 100
    dags_are_paused_at_creation = True
    max_active_runs_per_dag = 4
    load_examples = False
    load_default_connections = False
    plugins_folder = /opt/airflow/plugins
    execute_tasks_new_python_interpreter = False
    fernet_key = some_fernet_key
    donot_pickle = True
    dagbag_import_timeout = 30.0
    dagbag_import_error_tracebacks = True
    dagbag_import_error_traceback_depth = 5
    dag_file_processor_timeout = 50
    task_runner = StandardTaskRunner
    default_impersonation = airflow
    security =
    unit_test_mode = False
    enable_xcom_pickling = False
    killed_task_cleanup_time = 60
    dag_run_conf_overrides_params = True
    dag_discovery_safe_mode = True
    default_task_retries = 3
    default_task_weight_rule = downstream
    min_serialized_dag_update_interval = 5
    min_serialized_dag_fetch_interval = 5
    max_num_rendered_ti_fields_per_task = 30
    check_slas = True
    xcom_backend = airflow.models.xcom.BaseXCom
    lazy_load_plugins = False
    lazy_discover_providers = False
    max_db_retries = 3
    hide_sensitive_var_conn_fields = True
    sensitive_var_conn_names =
    default_pool_task_slot_count = 128
    sql_engine_collation_for_ids = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    max_queued_runs_per_dag = 50
    
    [logging]
    base_log_folder = /var/log/airflow
    remote_logging = False
    remote_log_conn_id =
    google_key_path =
    remote_base_log_folder =
    encrypt_s3_logs = False
    logging_level = INFO
    fab_logging_level = INFO
    logging_config_class =
    colored_console_log = True
    colored_log_format = [%(blue)s%(asctime)s%(reset)s] {%(blue)s%(filename)s:%(reset)s%(lineno)d} %(log_color)s%(levelname)s%(reset)s - %(log_color)s%(message)s%(reset)s
    colored_formatter_class = airflow.utils.log.colored_log.CustomTTYColoredFormatter
    log_format = [%(asctime)s] {%(filename)s:%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s - %(message)s
    simple_log_format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)s - %(message)s
    task_log_prefix_template = {{ti.dag_id}}-{{ti.task_id}}-{{execution_date}}-{{try_number}}
    log_filename_template = {{ ti.dag_id }}/{{ ti.task_id }}/{{ ts }}/{{ try_number }}.log
    log_processor_filename_template = {{ filename }}.log
    dag_processor_manager_log_location = /var/log/airflow/dag_processor_manager/dag_processor_manager.log
    task_log_reader = task
    extra_logger_names =
    worker_log_server_port = 8793
    
    [metrics]
    statsd_on = False
    statsd_host = localhost
    statsd_port = 8125
    statsd_prefix = airflow
    statsd_allow_list =
    stat_name_handler =
    statsd_datadog_enabled = False
    statsd_datadog_tags =
    
    [secrets]
    backend =
    backend_kwargs =
    
    [cli]
    api_client = airflow.api.client.local_client
    endpoint_url = http://airflow.xyz.com:8443
    
    [debug]
    fail_fast = True
    
    [api]
    enable_experimental_api = False
    auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.default
    maximum_page_limit = 100
    fallback_page_limit = 100
    google_oauth2_audience =
    google_key_path =
    access_control_allow_headers =
    access_control_allow_methods =
    access_control_allow_origins =
    access_control_allow_origin =
    
    [lineage]
    backend =
    
    [atlas]
    sasl_enabled = False
    host =
    port = 21000
    username =
    password =
    
    [operators]
    default_owner = airflow
    default_cpus = 2
    default_ram = 512
    default_disk = 512
    default_gpus = 0
    default_queue = default
    allow_illegal_arguments = True
    
    [hive]
    default_hive_mapred_queue =
    mapred_job_name_template =
    
    [webserver]
    base_url = http://airflow.xyz.com:8443
    default_ui_timezone = PST8PDT
    web_server_host = 0.0.0.0
    web_server_port = 8443
    web_server_ssl_cert = /ssl_location/xyz.com.crt
    web_server_ssl_key = /ssl_location/xyz.com.key
    session_backend = database
    web_server_master_timeout = 120
    web_server_worker_timeout = 120
    worker_refresh_batch_size = 1
    worker_refresh_interval = 6000
    reload_on_plugin_change = True
    secret_key = a_secret_key
    workers = 4
    worker_class = sync
    access_logfile = /var/log/airflow/webserver-access.log
    error_logfile = /var/log/airflow/webserver-error.log
    access_logformat =
    expose_config = True
    expose_hostname = True
    expose_stacktrace = True
    dag_default_view = tree
    dag_orientation = LR
    log_fetch_timeout_sec = 5
    log_fetch_delay_sec = 2
    log_auto_tailing_offset = 30
    log_animation_speed = 1000
    hide_paused_dags_by_default = False
    page_size = 100
    navbar_color = #fff
    default_dag_run_display_number = 30
    enable_proxy_fix = False
    proxy_fix_x_for = 1
    proxy_fix_x_proto = 1
    proxy_fix_x_host = 1
    proxy_fix_x_port = 1
    proxy_fix_x_prefix = 1
    cookie_secure = False
    cookie_samesite = Lax
    default_wrap = False
    x_frame_enabled = False
    show_recent_stats_for_completed_runs = True
    update_fab_perms = True
    session_lifetime_minutes = 43200
    auto_refresh_interval = 3
    
    [email]
    email_backend = airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp
    email_conn_id = smtp_default
    default_email_on_retry = True
    default_email_on_failure = True
    
    [smtp]
    smtp_host = mail.xyz.com
    smtp_starttls = False
    smtp_ssl = False
    smtp_port = 25
    smtp_mail_from = airflow@xyz.com
    smtp_timeout = 30
    smtp_retry_limit = 5
    
    [sentry]
    sentry_on = False
    sentry_dsn =
    
    [celery_kubernetes_executor]
    kubernetes_queue = kubernetes
    
    [celery]
    celery_app_name = airflow.executors.celery_executor
    worker_concurrency = 16
    worker_umask = 0o077
    broker_url = mysql+mysqldb://airflowdbuser:some_password@localhost:3306/airflow_db
    result_backend = mysql+mysqldb://airflowdbuser:some_password@localhost:3306/airflow_db
    flower_host = 0.0.0.0
    flower_url_prefix =
    flower_port = 5555
    flower_basic_auth =
    sync_parallelism = -1
    celery_config_options = airflow.config_templates.default_celery.DEFAULT_CELERY_CONFIG
    ssl_active = False
    ssl_key =
    ssl_cert =
    ssl_cacert =
    pool = prefork
    operation_timeout = 10.0
    task_track_started = True
    task_adoption_timeout = 600
    task_publish_max_retries = 3
    worker_precheck = True
    worker_autoscale =
    
    [celery_broker_transport_options]
    
    [dask]
    cluster_address = 127.0.0.1:8786
    tls_ca =
    tls_cert =
    tls_key =
    
    [scheduler]
    job_heartbeat_sec = 5
    scheduler_heartbeat_sec = 5
    num_runs = -1
    scheduler_idle_sleep_time = 2
    min_file_process_interval = 5
    dag_dir_list_interval = 60
    print_stats_interval = 5
    pool_metrics_interval = 5.0
    scheduler_health_check_threshold = 15
    orphaned_tasks_check_interval = 300.0
    child_process_log_directory = /opt/airflow/log/scheduler
    scheduler_zombie_task_threshold = 300
    catchup_by_default = False
    max_tis_per_query = 512
    use_row_level_locking = True
    max_dagruns_to_create_per_loop = 20
    max_dagruns_per_loop_to_schedule = 20
    schedule_after_task_execution = True
    parsing_processes = 4
    file_parsing_sort_mode = modified_time
    use_job_schedule = False
    allow_trigger_in_future = False
    dependency_detector = airflow.serialization.serialized_objects.DependencyDetector
    trigger_timeout_check_interval = 5
    
    [triggerer]
    default_capacity = 1000
    
    [kerberos]
    ccache = /tmp/airflow_krb5_ccache
    principal = airflow
    reinit_frequency = 3600
    kinit_path = kinit
    keytab = airflow.keytab
    forwardable = True
    include_ip = True
    
    [github_enterprise]
    api_rev = v3
    
    [elasticsearch]
    host =
    log_id_template = {{dag_id}}-{{task_id}}-{{execution_date}}-{{try_number}}
    end_of_log_mark = end_of_log
    frontend =
    write_stdout = False
    json_format = False
    json_fields = asctime, filename, lineno, levelname, message
    host_field = host
    offset_field = offset
    
    [elasticsearch_configs]
    use_ssl = False
    verify_certs = True
    
    [kubernetes]
    pod_template_file =
    worker_container_repository =
    worker_container_tag =
    namespace = default
    delete_worker_pods = True
    delete_worker_pods_on_failure = False
    worker_pods_creation_batch_size = 1
    multi_namespace_mode = False
    in_cluster = True
    kube_client_request_args =
    delete_option_kwargs =
    enable_tcp_keepalive = True
    tcp_keep_idle = 120
    tcp_keep_intvl = 30
    tcp_keep_cnt = 6
    verify_ssl = False
    worker_pods_pending_timeout = 300
    worker_pods_pending_timeout_check_interval = 120
    worker_pods_queued_check_interval = 60
    worker_pods_pending_timeout_batch_size = 100
    
    [smart_sensor]
    use_smart_sensor = True
    shard_code_upper_limit = 10000
    shards = 5
    sensors_enabled = NamedHivePartitionSensor
    
    [code_editor]
    enabled = True
    git_enabled = True
    git_cmd = /bin/git
    git_default_args = -c color.ui=true
    git_init_repo = False
    root_directory = /opt/airflow/dags
    line_length = 120
    string_normalization = True
    mount_name = Airflow_Logs
    mount_path = /opt/airflow/logs
```

Comment: Have you ever try do chown or chgrp in dag python file?
Like ```chown airflow mydagfile.py```

Comment: Did you ever solve this, @unsupervised?